# How to stick layout while keypad is shown to the Window

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made some layout in my application. . .
I have use Main layout as relative layout. now while i m Use the Keypad to write something at that time keypad in the Screen is displayd and the whole layout goes on the uper side of the keypad view. .  So how to Stop moving this layout while opening the Keypad view to write something ?
Please help me. . . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `adjustPan` to your manifest file in the declaration of the corresponding activity:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
.
.
</activity>
```